# Audio device disappeared

Tags: audio, drivers, hdmi, windows-11

I have a rather complex setup. I have 4 audio cards(external and internal sound cards) and I run several virtual audio devices.

I had everything working more or less(I'd get problems with VAC crashing when computer is put to sleep but I just re-run the repeater). Everything, again, was working fine until a few hours ago.

I got around to installing an external audio interface. I used it for about 30 minutes as I was testing and setting up and everything was working fine.

I then moved on to other things. About 30 minutes later I try to get my hdmi audio device to use with my monitor(which I have my headphones plugged in and I use when I want to use my head phones).

Then all off a sudden I can't get any audio out of the hdmi device. Two of my audio devices stop working and seem to no longer be recognized by windows.

I go to sound devices and device manager and they are not showing up. I show "hidden devices" and they do show up. I try to use the update drivers and such and nothing works.

I then reinstall one of the devices audio drivers and it is working but the hdmi device is still not working. I tried uninstalling all the devices associated with it but now it's not even showing up when I use scan hardware for changes.

Besides the obvious issue of windows 11 removing my audio devices(seems to be some "intelligent code" that messages around with audio and I guess the new drivers for the new device caused issues with the older drivers) I can't seem to get the hdmi audio to install. There are no drivers for this device so I can't just reinstall the drivers like I could for the other device(which also seems to have some buggy drivers).

How can I get hdmi audio drivers to install for the device? I can't even locate the device now(it is as if it failed but I don't think the hardware is damaged).

Comment: `but I don't think the hardware is damaged` .. no probably not damaged but a quick boot into a Linux Live ISO often makes things clear.

Comment: Anything change after reboot? I have a pro audio rig that will only work if it is enumerated at boot & not allowed to sleep. If it sleeps, or if I were to unplug/plug it, I have to reboot.

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately no ;/ Tried rebooting, installing all the other drivers. It seems that something(windows or the install of the device) blocked or removed the hdmi audio device/driver(tried turning off monitor, replugging monitor cable, etc). Everything was working fine until I installed the drivers for the other device... again, worked fine for about 30 minutes or so then just magically disappeared.

Comment: @Tetsujin I imagine if I could "install drivers" for the monitor and it's onboard audio that it would work but there are no drivers to install. I might just have to do without ;/ Just very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by first going to the trouble shooter under system and it showed the device and then popped up a dialog to disable effects. There are no effects but after messing with some settings it started showing back up.

My guess is that the driver I installed for the new device must have trashed the other drivers or something got corrupted. I really didn't do anything different as I did use the troubleshooter before except I uninstalled and reinstalled a few times since then.